# How to change ubuntu app menu icon color

Tags: icons, appmenu

[image: desktop of ubuntu]

How can I change the color of ubuntu show application icon for active, hover and normal sate.

Comment: Seems you are using dash to panel extension.. Are you trying to achive active hover etc For this case? Or default Ubuntu dock?

Comment: for dash to pan.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the icon of the menu in Dash-to-Panel then follow these steps

- Right-click on the panel
- Choose **Dash to Panel Settings**
- Scroll down till you can see **Show Applications Button** and click the Settings gear
- Click the button "None"
- A file explorer dialog box will open up
- Browse and select the file you want to keep as the icon and then click **Open**

Now your icon will show as the app menu icon